# node-inspector with vim and CoffeeScript

Tags: node.js, vim, coffeescript, vim-plugin, node-inspector

I installed node-inspector with help of npm in the following way:

```
npm install --prefix /home/uqmlore1/apps/node_modules -g node-inspector
```

Now, I just wonder whether [this plugin](https://github.com/sidorares/node-vim-debugger) is for node-inspector or not.

If yes it is possible to integrate the the following commands in Vim?

```
node-inspector &
coffee --nodejs --debug app.coffee &
google-chrome http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 &
google-chrome http://127.0.0.1:3000 &
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. It's an agent service similar to node-inspector, but instead of communicating to html-based devtools frontend over websockets it talks to vim using [netbeans protocol](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/netbeans.html). And strictly speaking it's not a vim plugin - you just start it after you started your script with `--debug`/`--debug-brk` switch, no need to copy to vim plugins. Feel free to ask questions (or better, open github issue if you need any help)

Comment: Yes, the issue tracker is the best place for any further discussion.